# Is Flyway 5.0 dropping support for Redshift?

Tags: flyway

Looking through the git repo, I see a commit with the comment of "Dropped support for Greenplum, Redshift and Vertica". Will Redshift not be supported in the next release?

Answer (score 1):

No. Support is still there: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/redshift

We have no plans to drop it.